# Where are GitAhead logs put?

Tags: debugging, github, logging

I have build GitAhead on my PC under Linux.  It looks OK when I run it.  Actually it is vy nice to look at.

However I have been having trouble with the Github login and I want to examine the log output.  I used the "-d" switch and enabled logging.  But nothing tells me where to look for the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to [build a debug version with `--debug=yes`](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/blob/53d6ddc65cf5acee7d254ea991363dc4d1851f68/dep/scintilla/scintilla-3.6.0/qt/ScintillaEditPy/sepbuild.py#L63) (should be the same as `-d`)

Then, since [gitahead issue 13](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues/13) is still open, it is possible that logs are, for now, limited to stdout, and not saved to a file.